# Selenium WebDriver fails with NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below mentioned error. Please advise if i am not able to provide correct path to the element.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//form[@id="extended-nav-search"]/input[1]"}
```

Here is my complete code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
my_driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
my_driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
my_driver.maximize_window()
email = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_key-login"]')
email.send_keys('abc@gmail.com')
time.sleep(2)
password = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_password-login"]')
password.send_keys('XXXXXX')
time.sleep(2)
login = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-primary"]')
login.click()
time.sleep(2)
search = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="extended-nav-search"]/input[1]')
search.send_keys("python programmer")
button = my_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search-controls-wormhole"]/button')
button.click()
```

Above code has error in Line 15th of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the element you're looking for has an id, you should really use `find_element_by_id`. To send keys to the search input, you need to then find the child  element 'input' and you can use xpath for that. You can also do the search by sending `Keys.ENTER` from `selenium.webdriver.common.keys`. All in all:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#
# ...
#
search = my_driver.find_element_by_id("extended-nav-search")
search = search.find_element_by_xpath("//input")
search.send_keys("python programmer")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: You are right , thought i have some other issue in program now . But what you told me 100% right and working